# Java how to call a method from a child class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm learning Swing to make GUI in java. My goal is to have 1 mainGUI class to initialize everything and another class that controls all the button.

What I'm doing now is I have a mainGUI which has:

```
public class mainGUI(){
.... (main and initialize things here) ....

protected JButton btnLogin;
public void initialize(){
    btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            _buttonLogin();
        }
    });
}

protected void _buttonLogin(){};
}
```

Then in my buttonControl I have:

```
public class buttonControl extends mainGUI{
@Override
protected void _buttonLogin(){
    if (isLogin == true){
        btnLogin.setEnabled(false); 
    } else {
        // somthing else
    }
}
}
```

The program actually works but not as i expected. When i click on the "login" button, the login button is not set to unclickable. If i don't have the _buttonLogin method in the mainGUI class then I cannot call it from buttonControl class.

I'm just wondering is my approach right in this situation? or any other neat way to have a separated listener class?

Thank you so much

Comment: am I the only one thinking that the OP's approach is very convoluted?

Comment: Why are you trying to make things complicated? you have the addActionListener(...) method, so why don't you just execute whatever action you want in same block. And _buttonLogin() is instance method of buttonControl class, i think the way you are calling is not correct.

Comment: thanks, because in my GUI i have 5 buttons so I just want to keep all the listener in a separated class, i know that's how i made thing convoluted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a Single class for control all the buttons you have you can create a ButtonControl class which can register and de-register buttons to it and handle its events inside the control class. A Simple example code is given

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MainUI extends JFrame{

ButtonController buttonController;

public MainUI() {
    super();
    buttonController=new ButtonController(this);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    JTextField userName=new JTextField();
    JPasswordField passwordField=new JPasswordField();

    JButton loginButton=new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.setActionCommand(ButtonController.LOGIN_COMMAND);

    JButton cancelButton=new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setActionCommand(ButtonController.CANCEL_COMMAND);

    JPanel contentPane=new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    contentPane.add(new JLabel("Username : "));
    contentPane.add(userName);
    contentPane.add(new JLabel("Password : "));
    contentPane.add(passwordField);
    contentPane.add(loginButton);
    contentPane.add(cancelButton);

    buttonController.registerButton(loginButton);
    buttonController.registerButton(cancelButton);

    setContentPane(contentPane);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pack();
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainUI ui=new MainUI();
    ui.setVisible(true);
}


}


class ButtonController implements ActionListener
{
private MainUI mainUI;

public static String LOGIN_COMMAND="Login";
public static String CANCEL_COMMAND="Cancel";

public ButtonController(MainUI mainUi ) {
    this.mainUI=mainUi;
}

public void registerButton(JButton button)
{
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

public void deRegisterButton(Button button)
{
    button.removeActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals(LOGIN_COMMAND))
    {
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals(CANCEL_COMMAND))
    {
        mainUI.dispose();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that helps you :). Please try to follow [java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). It'll be a good practise

Answer (score 4):

For one you're misusing inheritance. You don't use inheritance to gain access to variables. For that you should use composition.

For example, ButtonControl (and note that the first letter of any class should start with an upper case letter), could have a MainGui field which is passed into it via its constructors. Then the control class can call Gui methods.

```
class ButtonControl extends AbstractAction {
   MainGui gui;

   public ButtonControl(MainGui gui, String name, int mnemonic) {
      super(name);
      putValue(MNEMONIC, mnemmonic);
      this.gui = gui;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // ....
   }
}
```

And it could be used like so:

```
ButtonControl btnCtrl = new ButtonControl(this, "My Button", KeyEvent.VK_M);
JButton myButton = new JButton(btnCtrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time I've used swing, but we can only call the child class implementation by only from the child class object type :

```
mainGUI gui = new buttonControl();
```

we should pass buttonControl object type instance instead of mainGui instance if we want to let the caller use the implementation in buttonControl.

This related to [Polymorphism with overidding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Hopes this help..