# pass value from JTextField to ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, events, jdbc

I am writing a small GUI program for human resource management, class Insert is to add person to MySQL when button "submit" is clicked, and I have problem to pass the value read from `JTextField` to `HRActionListener` which is implemented from `ActionListener`, which allows only one parameter, I am trying to include all the buttons event in one class.

here are the code for Insert`,`AddGui`and`HRActionListener`

```
public class Insert {
private int id;
private String name;
private String sex;        
private String department;
private int salary;

public Insert(int id, String name, String sex, String department, int salary){
    this.id = id; 

    this.name = name;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.department = department;
    this.salary = salary;

}



public void insert(){
    Connection conn = DBconn.getConn();
    String sql = "insert into person values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;             
    try {
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,id);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,name);
        preparedStatement.setString(3,sex);
        preparedStatement.setString(4,department);
        preparedStatement.setInt(5,salary);
        //update
        int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("增加操作失败");
    } finally{ 

            try {
                if (preparedStatement!=null){
                preparedStatement.close();}
                if (conn != null){
                conn.close();}
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
               System.out.println("close failed");
            }
        }



    }


}
```

---

```
public class HRActionListener implements ActionListener{


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ) {
     String string = e.getActionCommand();
     if(string.equals("添加")){
         new AddGui().ShowAddGui();
     }}}
```

---

```
public class AddGui {
public void ShowAddGui() {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("添加");
Container con = new Container();
con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));

JLabel label = new JLabel("添加新员工");
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
con.add(label);

JButton id = new JButton("工号：");
JTextField idField = new JTextField(5);
panel.add(id); 
panel.add(idField);

JButton name = new JButton("姓名：");
JTextField nameField = new JTextField(5);
panel.add(name);
panel.add(nameField);

JButton sex = new JButton("性别：");
JTextField sexField = new JTextField(5);
panel.add(sex);
panel.add(sexField);

JButton depart = new JButton("部门：");
JTextField departField = new JTextField(5);
panel.add(depart);
panel.add(departField);

JButton salary = new JButton("工资：");
JTextField salaryField = new JTextField(5);
panel.add(salary);
panel.add(salaryField);


JButton addTo = new JButton("确定");
addTo.addActionListener(new HRActionListener());

JButton deleteTo = new JButton("取消");
panel.add(addTo);
panel.add(deleteTo);

con.add(panel);
frame.add(con);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(220, 270);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);}}
```

Comment: Are you trying to open same new frame instances on every button click?

Comment: sorry here may have some chinese char causes misunderstandings! What I want there is when add button clicked, the information user input can be inserted into database!

Comment: If that is true then why are you calling `new AddGui().ShowAddGui();` in your actionPerformed? this will always create a new frame. instead you need to call insert method here.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501246/java-how-to-call-a-method-from-a-child-class/24502242#24502242) answer hope it'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and make your `AddGui` class implement your `ActionListener`

```
class AddGui implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField idField = new JTextField(5);
    //Other input fields

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Get all other fields here
        Insert record = new Insert(Integer.parseInt(idField.getText()), "name", "sex", "dept", 0);
        //call to insert()
    }
```

In this case, your button declaration should be:

```
JButton addTo = new JButton("");
addTo.addActionListener(this);
```